# How to properly build HTTP connection suffix

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

I have written code to get a location name using Google Maps reverse geocoding, for example:
[`http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7`](http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7)

How can I add an appropriate HTTP connection suffix to the above URL?

I have tried the following function:

```
private static String getConnectionStringForGoogleMap(){
    String connectionString="";
    if(WLANInfo.getWLANState()==WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED){
        connectionString="&interface=wifi";
    }   
     else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS){
         connectionString = "&deviceside=false";
    }
        else if((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)==CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT){
            String carrierUid=getCarrierBIBSUid();
            if(carrierUid == null) {
                connectionString = "&deviceside=true";
            }
            else{
                 connectionString = "&deviceside=false&connectionUID="+carrierUid + "&ConnectionType=mds-public";
                }

            }
     else if(CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
        {

        }
    return connectionString;
    }
```

When I run the application in the simulator, I create the URL like this:
`http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7+getConnectionStringForGoogleMap();`

But I get a tunnel exception and am not sure what to do next.

This URL also leads to an exception:
`http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7&deviceside=false&ConnectionType=mds-public`

As does:
`http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public`

I am confused about what to do to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely want semi-colons (;) and not ampersands (&).  Are you tring to run this on the simulator?  If so, do you have the MDS simulator running?  That is required in order to use `devicside=false` on the simulator.

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public-The url also falls in exception

Answer (score 2):

Try using Versatile Monkey's [networking helper class](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/) to find the best path for your HTTP connection and avoid those tunnel exceptions. And form the URL with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [very good posting](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-HTTP-Connection-code-and-BIS-B-Access/m-p/653175) about this on the BlackBerry Java development forum, complete with sample HTTP connection code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using following
It worked for me

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7&;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting OS5 and above you can use [ConnectionFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html). This takes a lot of the hard work out of establishing the correct connection type.